# Will a git reset --soft origin/master fail if you have been using git merge origin/master?

Tags: git

When I submit PRs at work sometimes it's a lot cleaner (it's all vanity) to have 1 commit instead of 30. So typically I might do this:

```
git add . && git merge origin/master
git commit -am "abc"
# make more changes
git add . && git commit -am "abc"
git merge origin/master
```

and then to make things into one 1 commit, I might try:

```
git reset --soft origin/dev
```

the problem is I get the feeling that this won't reset far enough in history. Because of my merge commits. Perhaps the only way to do it right is to do:

```
sha="$(git merge-base --fork-point HEAD origin/master)"
git reset --soft "$sha"
```

but I get the feeling that the merge-base command will only go back as the most recent merge commit between origin/master and my branch?

Comment: Even though you can achieve what you want, I advise you not to use single mammooth commits. Atomic commits can be very explanatory about the context and reason of a change later if that information becomes critical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git reset
```

resets the current head to a given state.

```
git reset --soft <commit>
```

will reset the head to the state of the commit given, or the last commit by default. So, if you want to make your command the next commit and you know the hash of the previous commit, then you can run the command above, but make sure you pass the correct hash.

You can browse commit hashes via

```
git log
```